# problems with endpoint configuration - amazon alexa custom skill

Tags: java, ssl, webserver, alexa-skills-kit, sslhandshakeexception

I'm currently facing some troubles by reaching my **https-endpoint** for my **alexa-custom-skill**.

My endpoint is an internal PC on my network. For reaching this web server I use a **DDNS** `(<server>.linkpc.net)` for my router. The router itself has a port forwarding `(443 => internal WebServer Port)`. That means the current architecture is:

> Alexa => Router (.linkpc.net):443 => :
>   => RESPONSE => ROUTER => Alexa

I also created a self-signed certificate, that is placed inside a jks and loaded by my WebServer. 
This solution works well, by calling the URL `(<server>.linkpc.net/xxx/xxx)` via browser from outside my network. I receive a message that connection is unsecured due to an untrusted certificate (my self-signed one). But that is a normal behaviour.

I imported the self-signed certificate to own "*SSL certificate*" via Amazon DEV Console (**PEM** Format). 
From my point of view, everything should be fine, but I get the following error by sending a request to Amazon Dev Console:
"The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid."
If I'm going to copy the **xml-text** and insert it into JSON chapter I got:

> "There was an exception during the SSL handshake. Please check the
>   certificate you have provided."

I also created a BreakPoint in Eclipse. It works by using a Browser, but it didn't by using Alexa Dev Console. No response in the code. That means, from my personal point of view, the request is not even reaching my WebServer at all. There are three possible explanations (maybe):

- The router provides the wrong certificate to Alexa (strange, because it should not work as a proxy and shouldn't need the self-signed certificate?!)
- Self-Signed certificate was wrongly built for Amazon Alexa ?!
- A bug inside amazon dev console (unlikely)

Could you please support? :-)
Greetings
Richard